# How to install Ubuntu from Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8 just remotely by single click?

Tags: installation, windows, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 PC running in USA via VNC (when with a public IP), Logmein (when behind complex NAT) remotely I am watching and logged in.

But the Windows 7 PC does not need Windows, it requires Ubuntu and I have the permission to do so. But what I do not have is my hands and eyes remotely.

So, how can I install Ubuntu in a working Windows 7 PC, so that after installation it reboot and sends me remote login link in my email. And every-time I have Ubuntu.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What is Windows XP, 7?

Comment: @RolandTaylor: My friend is using Windows 7. And remotely i am logged in, now he wants me to install the Ubuntu and put my application, which does not work under Windows 7. So i told my friend can i remove your Windows 7? He says yes you can, but i am leaving to holiday in 5 minutes will be back after 1 year. Now i am remotely connected but i can not install Ubuntu because how? Is there any way?

Comment: You're asking a very difficult thing here.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225693/what-are-the-easy-ways-to-install-ubuntu-remotely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if what you are asking is possible to do the way you want without anybody to put hands on the remote pc.

The only way I can think for now is to install a VM (virtualbox for example) and install ubuntu on it, this way you will be able to control the Ubuntu machine after install (and reboot to configure it). You may even prepare a virtual HD file locally and transfer it to the remote machine so you don't need to install ubuntu remotely.