# Remotely install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, remote-access, remote

I am connecting remotely to a laptop running windows 7 which I do not have physical access. I want to install ubuntu on it.

- The laptop connects to the router wirelessly, the ubuntu image has to somehow be preconfigured to connect to the password protected network.
- Remote connection is over the internet
- Computer is an inspiron 1501

Is this possible and how would I go about it?

Same question but no real answer: [How to install Ubuntu from Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8 just remotely by single click?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92520/how-to-install-ubuntu-from-windows-xp-vista-7-8-just-remotely-by-single-click)

Comment: Ubuntu does not really support this without making a highly customized custom iso. You can, however, do this easily with Fedora (or RHEL).

Comment: I would not mind a different linux distro. Do you have any lnks for what you mentioned?

Comment: google search. There are several options and the Fedora installer disk has ssh enabled so you can ssh in. PXE boot, kickstart is IMO easiest, pxe boot. http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Installation_Guide/sn-automating-installation.html or similar.

Comment: Is it possible or within budget to purchase/rent/borrow a network KVM?  Ebay has some for very cheap.

Comment: Also, might be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/92520/how-to-install-ubuntu-from-windows-xp-vista-7-8-just-remotely-by-single-click?noredirect=1&lq=1 However that was a LONG time ago, and things may have changed...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. You'd need to somehow modify the Ubuntu installation to put the WiFi network config in. There's also no way you could install it remotely because the setup requires personalization and doesn't support remote connections.

Comment: Not really all that great an answer. with persistence it will save wireless passwords and you can install a ssh or vnc server ....

Comment: @bodhi.zazen But you can do none of that remotely.

Comment: No, but you can configure the usb locally and send the usb remote. You have to remote boot the ubuntu image somehow, and can do so with peristance.

Comment: But then you still have to install SSH onto a Live Boot that isn't accepting remote connections. @bodhi.zazen

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Also, saving WiFi passwords is useless, since there's no way to connect to the network in the first place.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I did take the part about loading saved networks out, though.

Comment: You configure networking for the remote location. ie set a static IP, enter the network password, install a reverse VNC server, whatever. Then you ship and boot the usb. This is similar to installing Ubuntu locally on a rack server, then sending the rack server to a server farm.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I don't understand. This person has a remote computer that they want to install Ubuntu on it remotely. How can VNC be set up on something that isn't installed?

Comment: How do you boot the remote computer ? With an ubuntu live USB ? boot the live ubuntu usb locally, with persistence, install VNC, ssh, whatever, configure the network with a static IP as it will when it is booted remote. The installed servers and network configuration will be saved via persistence. Then send the flash drive remote and boot it.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen That makes sense, but only if the local computer connects to the same WiFi network. Or can you manually set up a WiFi network on Ubuntu? If you can, I'll delete my answer and you can post that as one.

Comment: You manually configure your wireless. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic

Answer (score 0):

**Do you need it bare metal install?**

- If not, Install VirtualBox, then install Ubuntu inside that?   (free)
- If so, Maybe you can ship a USB to someone on-site and walk them through it?  (almost free)
- If so, Is it possible or within budget to purchase/rent/borrow a network KVM?  Ebay has some for very cheap.  With that, and someone putting a bootable USB stick in, then you can do it. There are other ways with PXE or other even more complex solutions generally intended for datacenter style metal box prepping.